# Linux text editor supporting bookmarks

Tags: linux, editor, bookmarks, nagios

I have about 19k lines of *configuration* files (actually in a DSL - Nagios) that I need to do a bunch of analysis on, come up with a refactor plan, and then implement.

I'm looking for - but not finding - a GUI text editor for Linux that supports **global** bookmarks - i.e. I can click on a line, give it a name/tag, and have it show up in a global list that I can click on and then jump back to. The key point is that it has to work across files, so I can jump from a location in one file to the corresponding location in another.

Since it's a DSL, I haven't been able to find any IDE that natively supports the language. I've tried Kate, but the bookmarks list is per-file only, and "tags" each line with the text of the line itself, no way to add a custom note.

Is anyone aware of an application that meets this objective feature set?

Comment: Did you try `emacs` ?

Comment: vim with [markers](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Using_marks)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Eclipse IDE.  Add both EclipseColorer - for syntax highlighting (try the .ini file format) and Eclipse Color Theme plugins.  Together, these plugins work quite well for highlighting Nagios config files.  It does the bookmarking and has a separate view port, that is detachable, to easily navigate them - even in multiple files.